# Enum covarience for virtual function return

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, covariance

Why does C++ not recognise `enum MyEnum : int` as being co-variant to `int`?

Example: http://ideone.com/Ns1O2d

```
#include <iostream>

enum FooType : int
{
    Crazy = 0,
    Cool
};

enum BarType : int
{
        Hello = Cool + 1,
        World
};

class Foo
{
public:
        Foo(void)
        {
        }

        ~Foo(void)
        {
        }

        virtual int getType(void) 
        {
                        return Crazy;
        }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
        Bar(void)
        {
        }

        ~Bar(void)
        {
        }

        virtual BarType getType(void)
        {
                return Hello;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Bar f = Bar();           
        std::cout << f.getType() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
prog.cpp:43:18: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual BarType Bar::getType()'
prog.cpp:26:14: error:   overriding 'virtual int Foo::getType()'
```

Comment: By simply changing the return type of `Bar::getType()` from `BarType` to `int` (and changing nothing else) you get the desired effect, though, right?

Comment: Because it is not... `FooType` and `BarType` are distinct types, you could `return (int)Crazy;` if you want to cast your `BarType` to an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Non-scoped enumeration types (i.e. the usual `enums`, as opposed to `enum class` and `enum struct`) provide implicit promotion to integer, i.e you can do this:

```
enum FooType : int { Crazy, Cool };
int val = Crazy; // promotion to integer
```

However, this does not work in reverse:

```
FooType val = 0;  // illegal
```

This follows from §7.2/5: *Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types*, in combination with §7.2/9: *The value of an enumerator or an object of an unscoped enumeration type is converted to an integer by integral promotion.*

I believe the reason for this rule is quite obvious: There can be (and, generally, are) integer values for which no corresponding enumerator is defined. In the example above, converting `0` and `1` would be theoretically possible, but converting `2` or any larger number could not be converted.

However, if the enumeration were **covariant** to its underlying type (`int` in your example), in the sense you defined it, the following would be possible:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo(void) {}
  virtual int getType(void) 
  {
    return Crazy;
  }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Bar(void) {}
  virtual BarType getType(void)
  {
    return Foo::getType();
  }
};
```

In the derived class, `Bar::getType()` has now been defined to return a `BarType`, but it does this by calling the inherited function `Foo::getType()`, which is entirely legitimate.

If this was possible as written, `Bar::getType()` would have to implicitly convert the `int` that results from `Foo::getType()` to an `int`. And this can't be, as explained above.

---

However, you can still achieve what your code seems to intend by declaring `Bar::getType` in the same way as `Foo:getType`, and return a `BarType` (which is implicitly promoted to `int`):

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Bar(void) {}
  virtual int getType(void)
  {
    return Hello;
  }
};
```

Note that this only works if the underlying type is `int` (which it is because you fixed it to `int` in the declaration of the enumeration), and if the enumeration is not scoped (i.e. not using `enum class` or `enum struct`).

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not work like that. The idea of covariant return types only works for references or pointers to objects that are subclasses of the original return type.

When you write `enum class MyEnum : int`, you are not specifying a subclass, you are specifying that MyEnum will be implemented by the int type.

You are only allowed to do the following:

```
class Base {
  public:
  virtual Base* foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
  Derived* foo();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

typed `enum`s where just recently adopted into C++.  There are plenty of things that `enum`s should do in an ideal world -- we should be able to iterate over the defined values, we should be able to make them into algebras, we should be allowed to extend them like we do `class`es, and we probably should be able to make a `virtual` function that returns a covariant `enum` like you are asking.

But we cannot.

Now, what we can do is the following:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual int getType() const { return 0; }
};

enum Bird : int { Chicken = 0, Duck = 1 };

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  Bird getBirdType() const { return static_cast<Bird>(getType()); }
  virtual int getType() const override { return Chicken; }
};
```

where the old signature (`getType`) remains exposed, with a new function (`getBirdType`) gives us the type-corrected version.

The world might be a better place if we could write `Bird Derived::getType() const override`, but unless you agree with Leibniz, we don't live in that world.  Adding features to C++ costs standard development time and costs compilers time to implement it.  So features that get added to C++ tend to be ones that have been tested in compilers on the market, and whose cost is worth the benefit and demand.

If you really want that feature, I encourage you to get involved in C++ standardization efforts!

Answer (score 2):

> Why does C++ not recognise `enum MyEnum : int` as being co-variant to `int`?

Because it isn't – whereas objects of derived class types may be implicitly treated as objects of their public base types, strongly-typed enums are, well, *strongly-typed*. I.e., they may *not* be implicitly treated as objects of their underlying type, and that being said, are not covariant candidates.